# Cardinality function is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Let also $g$ be a function, defined by the following condition:for each $a \in [0, + \infty]$ $$g(a)=\text{card} \{ x \in [0, 1] | f(x) = a \} \in [0, + \infty)$$ I would like to prove that $g$ is also a measurable function.  Are there any hints that might help?

Probably, it is worth trying to prove it more or less directly, by checking that $\{ a \in [0, + \infty] | g(a) < c \}$ is measurable for any $c$, but this approach does not seem to be clear enough, since the preimage of $g$ would be some cardinal number.

Comment: Do you know Lusin's separation theorem?

Comment: And what is $X?$

Comment: @zhw Fixed. Now $X = [0, 1]$

Comment: @tomasz So far -- no, i haven't bumped into the statement. I've just skimmed through it right now. If i got it correctly, it states that if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint analytic subsets (continuous images of Polish spaces) of a Polish space, then there is a Borel subset $X$ that separates them ($A \subset X$, $B \cap X = \emptyset$.)

Comment: Are you thinking of $g$ as a function with values in $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}\cup\{\infty\}$? ($\infty$ indicates that the level set in question is infinite.) Or do you wish to distinguish between cases when $\{x\in[0,1]\mid f(x)=a\}$ is countable and when it is uncountable?

Comment: @JohnDawkins  $g$ is a function with range $[0, + \infty)$, so, as you have written above, the $\infty$ means that the level set is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

By the intermediate value theorem, for any interval $I\subseteq [0,1]$, the 
set $A:=\{f(x),x\in I\}$ is an interval, and so is a Borel set.

Fix $n$ and let $I_i=[i/n,(i+1)/n)$ for $i=0,1,\dots, n-1$.
Now define the bounded, Borel measurable function 
$$g_n(a)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\bf 1}_{A_i}(a)+{\bf 1}_{\{f(1)\}}(a),$$
where $A_i=\{f(x), x\in I_i\}$.

We have $g_n(a)\uparrow g(a)$ as $n\to\infty$, which shows that $g$ is measurable.